# Do I need KSPSetOperators after PCSetOperators?

Tags: petsc

What I did is

1. Create some PC named pc, and PCSetOperators(pc,A,A,..);
2. Create KSP named ksp;
3. KSPSetPC(ksp,pc);

After the above process, am I still obliged to KSPSetOperators(ksp,A,A,..), or I can skip this?  From the source code of Petsc, it seems I do not need. Just want to make sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not strictly necessary in certain use cases, please call `KSPSetOperators()` anyway (perhaps instead of `PCSetOperators()`). This ensures that null space and setup information is consistent and manages initial guesses for repeated solution of linear systems ("Fischer guess"). Calling `KSPSetOperators()` with the same operators is essentially free.

Note that you can always `KSPGetPC()` and then configure the `PC`, instead of creating it yourself and using `KSPSetPC()`.